# Insercción de datos por Formulario PHP

Tags: php, formularios, php5

Buenas, tengo un formulario, que a veces a la hora de introducir datos me ingresa lo indicado al form pero las siguientes líneas indica error y no llego a visualizar el por que.

```
Notice: Undefined index: posicion in C:\xampp\htdocs\puo\vista\Tablas\puo\index.php on line 81

Notice: Undefined index: precio_total in C:\xampp\htdocs\puo\vista\Tablas\puo\index.php on line 87

Notice: Undefined index: descuento in C:\xampp\htdocs\puo\vista\Tablas\puo\index.php on line 88

Notice: Undefined index: iva_total in C:\xampp\htdocs\puo\vista\Tablas\puo\index.php on line 90
```

Dichas líneas son estas:

```
        case 'registrar':
        $alm->__SET('ano', $_REQUEST['ano']); 
        $alm->__SET('empresa', $_REQUEST['acronimo']); 
        $alm->__SET('acro_proyecto', $_REQUEST['proyecto']);
        $alm->__SET('partida', $_REQUEST['partida']);
        $alm->__SET('proveedor', $_REQUEST['proveedor']); 
        $alm->__SET('formadepago', $_REQUEST['formadepago']); 
        $alm->__SET('solicitado_por', $_REQUEST['solicitado_por']); 
        $alm->__SET('aprobado_por', $_REQUEST['aprobado_por']); 
        $alm->__SET('puo', $_REQUEST['puo']); 
        $alm->__SET('posicion', $_REQUEST['posicion']); 
        $alm->__SET('producto_servicio', $_REQUEST['producto_servicio']);
        $alm->__SET('cantidad', $_REQUEST['cantidad']);
        $alm->__SET('precio_unitario', $_REQUEST['precio_unitario']); 
        $alm->__SET('descuento_porcentaje', $_REQUEST['descuento_porcentaje']);
        $alm->__SET('iva', $_REQUEST['iva']); 
        $alm->__SET('precio_total', $_REQUEST['precio_total']); 
        $alm->__SET('descuento', $_REQUEST['descuento']);
        $alm->__SET('precio_uni_descuento', $_REQUEST['precio_uni_descuento']);
        $alm->__SET('iva_total', $_REQUEST['iva_total']); 
        $alm->__SET('total', $_REQUEST['total']);
```

Y provienen del form tal que así:

```
<td colspan="2">
    <input size="49px" class="form-control " type="text" name="precio_total"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('precio_total') : ''; ?>" onKeyUp="formula()" style="width:100%;" disabled onchange="change_documento9();"/>
</td>

<td>
    <select class="form-control" name="posicion" id="posicion" disabled="">
       <option value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('posicion') : ''; ?>"><?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('posicion') : ''; ?> </option>    
     </select>
 </td>

 <td colspan="2">
     <input size="49px" class="form-control " type="text" name="descuento"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('descuento') : ''; ?>" onKeyUp="formula()" style="width:100%;" disabled onchange="change_documento9();"/>
 </td>

<td colspan="2">
    <input size="49px" class="form-control " type="text" name="iva_total"  value="<?php echo isset($obj_categoria) ? $obj_categoria->__GET('iva_total') : ''; ?>" onKeyUp="formula()" style="width:100%;" disabled onchange="change_documento9();"/>
</td>
```

Y el Case que los registra es el siguiente:

```
    public function Registrar(Categoria $data) {
    try {
        $sql = ("INSERT IGNORE INTO puo (ano,empresa,acro_proyecto,partida,proveedor,formadepago,solicitado_por,aprobado_por,puo,posicion,producto_servicio,cantidad,precio_unitario,descuento_porcentaje,iva,precio_total,descuento,precio_uni_descuento,iva_total,total)
            VALUES (:an, :emp, :acrp, :par, :pro, :forma, :solici, :aproba, :pu, :posi, :proser, :cant, :preuni, :despor, :iv, :preto, :descu, :preundes, :ivt, :tot)");
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':an', $data->__GET('ano'), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':emp', $data->__GET('empresa'), PDO::PARAM_STR);                        
        $stmt->bindValue(':acrp', $data->__GET('acro_proyecto'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':par', $data->__GET('partida'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':pro', $data->__GET('proveedor'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':forma', $data->__GET('formadepago'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':solici', $data->__GET('solicitado_por'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':aproba', $data->__GET('aprobado_por'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':pu', $data->__GET('puo'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':posi', $data->__GET('posicion'), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':proser', $data->__GET('producto_servicio'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':cant', $data->__GET('cantidad'), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':preuni', $data->__GET('precio_unitario'), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':despor', $data->__GET('descuento_porcentaje'), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':iv', $data->__GET('iva'), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':preto', $data->__GET('precio_total'), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':descu', $data->__GET('descuento'), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':preundes', $data->__GET('precio_uni_descuento'), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':ivt', $data->__GET('iva_total'), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':tot', $data->__GET('total'), PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            echo "se insert� ";
        } else {

            echo "<script>alert('" . $data->__GET('puo') . " ya existe en la Tabla Usuarios');</script>";
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: De la impresión de que esta parte: `<select class="form-control" name="posicion" id="posicion" disabled="">` y las demás etiquetas que están dando la `notice Undefined index` no están realmente dentro del `<form>` que estás posteando. ¿Podrías poner el HTML completo del form y la forma en que lo estás posteando?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/synysevend90/teakr4Lf/1/ Te sirve por aqui?

Comment: Habría sido útil que pusieras  en la pregunta el código relevante solamente, donde te está fallando, de esa forma no obligas a tener que revisar tremendo trozo de código. De entrada, tienes una etiqueta llamada `posicion1` no `posición`. Luego, no veo por ningún lado donde haces post de tu ¿`form1`?

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que el formulario que quieres postear es el `form1`.

Te falta una función Javascript que haga el post, ligado por ejemplo a un botón del form. En este caso, el form tendrá este botón:

`<input type="button" onclick="enviarForm()" value="Enviar form">`

el cual al recibir un clic, llamará a la función `enviarForm()` de JS.

El formulario se puede enviar por otro medio, si lo prefieres. El problema es que de acuerdo a lo que he podido ver del código actual, no se está posteando.

También, revisa las etiquetas `name` de cada elemento del form, ya que por ejemplo, la etiqueta que *crees* que se llama posición, actualmente se llama *posicion1*.

```js
function enviarForm() {
  document.getElementById("form1").submit();
  console.log(
  document.forms["form1"].getElementsByTagName("input"));
  alert("Valor de id: "+document.getElementById("id").value);
  alert("Valor de posición: "+document.getElementById("posicion").value);
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" action="?action=registrar">
  Id:       <input type="text" name="id" id="id"><br> 
  Posicion: <input type="text" name="posicion" id="posicion"><br><br>
            <input type="button" onclick="enviarForm()" value="Enviar form">
</form>
```